# HTML5 File API Image Preview and Reset

Tags: html, file, api, preview

Plenty of examples of using HTML5 to preview an image selected in file field but I can't find any examples with a remove/reset link - after selecting image and writing image to canvas is it possible to reset field AND reset the image or effectively hide it?

Answer (score 0):

if you are referring to the html5imageupload by STBeets from [here](http://dev.html5ux.com/upload-image/) then you have to access the html5imageupload  object through the function of a callback. For instance, if you are applying this plugin to a #formuploader div:

```
$('#formuploader').html5imageupload
({
    onAfterProcessImage :   function(obj)
                            {
                                obj.reset();
                            }
});
```

You can do this with any of the callbacks available